# Show entries in a single category and then again in all categories except the previously excluded category

Tags: categories, stash

This one's got me.

I'm using Stash to capture a list of entries into a set_list. I want to get this list in two different areas on the page with different categories. If I were simply trying to display 2 different categories, match/against would work. However, what I'm trying to do seems to be a little more complicated. Here's what I want:

1. In the first get_list, I want to **show entries from all but one category**.
2. In the second get_list, I want to **show entries from the the single category I excluded in the first list**

The exact scenario is that I would like one list to show **all articles**, and the other list to show **only announcements**.

Here's what I'm starting off with:

```
{!-- Articles --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="articles" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="news"
        dynamic="no"
        orderby="sticky|entry_date"
        sort="desc|desc"
        sort_type="numeric|numeric"
        disable="pagination|member_data|category_fields"
    }
        {stash:sticky}{sticky}{/stash:sticky}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:summary}{article_summary}{/stash:summary}
        {stash:date}{entry_date}{/stash:date}
        {stash:url}{page_url}{/stash:url}
        {stash:image}{article_featured_image}{/stash:image}

        {!-- Get the category_id so we can match against them --}
        {stash:category_id}{categories}{category_id}{/categories}{/stash:category_id}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

So, that gives me my list of **all articles**. For my second list, it's as simple as using match/against to only show announcments:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="articles" match="#^13#" against="category_id"}
    <article>
        <p><a href="{url}"><i class="ss-icon ss-newspaper"></i> <span class="meta">{date format="%M %d, %Y"}</span> {title}</a></p>
    </article>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

It's the first list where I'm stumped. How do I capture **all entries *except* for those in category 13** without having to make another channel entries call?

I know I could just create 2 separate set_lists with 2 separate channel entry calls. One which has category="not 13" and another with category="13".

I also thought I could wrap 2 set_lists in the {cateogries} tag and, again use show="13" and show="not 13", but I don't see a way to do that without repeating my stash variable setters.

How do I keep this at a single channel entry call and keep it DRY?

### Update:

romans-8-31-39 pointed out a feature I didn't know existed, which was to NOT match a pattern when filtering a list. That answer is technically correct. When I went to implement that, I realized I'm already using match/against on my first list to match against sticky entries.

Would this be a use case for [the stash technique outlined here](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Filtering%20lists%20with%20match%20against)? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the technique.

Comment: It pains me, but this is where I am until I figure out a better way. http://pastie.org/9375301

Comment: I feel like I could use the pattern described here for the first list: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/NOT-matching-a-pattern-when-filtering-a-list

However, I'm already using match/against to filter on sticky entries in the first list, and I don't know of a way to use multiple columns in match/against.

Comment: Can you add the match/against from the first list you're using for sticky?

Comment: `{exp:stash:get_list name="articles" match="#^y$#" against="sticky"}`

Comment: Grr. Almost got it working using the "tracking" tecnnique at the bottom of the fitering lists technique, but the catch is that you can't use both tracking *and* match/against.

Comment: I figured out a way to deal with my unique scenario using a combination of all 3 techniques (regular match/against, the more advanced filtering, and tracking). I'm marking the answer from @Romans-8---31-39  correct since it 100% answered my original question without the unrelated complexity I found after digging deeper.

Comment: Glad you got it going -

Comment: In case anyone in interested in the final code. http://pastie.org/9375511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first list I think you're just looking for a regex that does NOT match the category you want to exclude. I haven't tested this, but try the regular expression

```
^(?!13$)
```

So you would end up with:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="articles" match="#^(?!13$)#" against="category_id"}
...
```

to see if that finds all items in your articles list that are not category 13.
(Updated, changed regex after test run.)

Comment: That does answer my question. I should (and will) clarify, I'm already using the match/against to filter on {sticky}. I think what I need is this: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Filtering%20lists%20with%20match%20against